# iphone- view loads slowly on 4 inch screen

Tags: view, xcode5, iphone-5, lag, autoresize

Okay, so I have an app with a system of views made for a 3.5 inch screen. Something about the autosizing four the four inch screen makes views load fine for the top 7/8 of the screen, but the bottom 1/8 loads with lag. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide much more detail for us to give you an answer. Is there code you can share that can replicate the problem? Does it only happen with certain types of assets or view? What have you tried?

Comment: I do not think that it is a problem with the code. It worked fine in xcode 4. Could it be due to the new autosizing features in xcode 5. I orignially coded the app in xcode three, and still rely on loading .xib files instead of using storyboard. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the animation I used to load the .xib files. It was outdated and slowed the view loading process down.